# Back Handler not working when I move back mutiple pages in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The scenario is I have 3 screens, from the 3rd screen when I hit the hardware back button, it navigates to 2nd screen. When I again hit the hardware back button, it does not navigate to 1st screen. Instead nothing changes in the screen.

This is how I have used the back handlers.

```js
this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
  'hardwareBackPress',
  this.onTabsBackPress,
);

onTabsBackPress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
  return true;
};
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Did you unsubscribe your listener on `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: Thank you @TuanLuong, I missed to unsubscribe. Now it is working fine.